# Arrange columns according to height

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap for grid.

When the an column is expanded the other columns which are on right are aligning properly but the elements which are left to it are not aligning properly.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="repeater" ng-repeat="student in students | filter : query">
  <div class="span{{12/columns}} col-sm-6 panel panel-warning">
   <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-5"><img ng-src = "img/{{student.img}}" width="80px;" class="img-circle"></div>
 <div class="col-md-7">
  <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top:20px;" ng-click="show=!show">{{student.name}}</button>
      <button type="button" class="close pull-right" ng-click="remove(student)">&times; </button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" ng-show="show">
     <tr><th style="padding-right:0px;">Father Name:</th><td>{{student.fathername}}</td>    </tr>
     <tr><th>Class: </th><td>{{student.class}}</td></tr>
     <tr><th>Subj1: </th><td>{{student.results.subj1}}</td></tr>
     <tr><th>subj2: </th><td>{{student.results.subj2}}</td></tr>
     <tr><th>subj3: </th><td>{{student.results.subj3}}</td></tr>
     <tr><th>subj4: </th><td>{{student.results.subj4}}</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/APLfD/6/) view in fullscreen view.

I want all the elements in the grid to align properly without leaving any place.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? A mockup screenshot of the layout you want would be really helpful

Comment: Please go through the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/APLfD/6/embedded/result/) and click on the buttons you can see the view there

Comment: I want all the elements to align properly without leaving waste space :-)

Comment: You might consider a JS library like [**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to help you achieve the masonry effect you're looking for. There is at least one [**Angular directive library**](https://github.com/mankindsoftware/angular-isotope) which may help. Or else, writing your own directives would not be terribly difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not entirely possible with bootstrap. To explain you why, the `.col-md-4` class has css property `float: left` which means whenever you open the right-most box, the left-side elements takes the height of the right-box, thus not allowing any other boxes below it.

You could get it working for the left and right elements by giving `float:right` for every last element in the row (in your case using `.col-md-4:nth-child(3n){ float:right; }`) like in the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TN84b/embedded/result/)** here but the middle element cannot be helped because it is still under `float:left`.

For your requirement, I recommend you use a JS library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which does exactly what you are expecting and used in cases where containers have variable heights and you want to fix them tightly, leaving no gap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ewNc6/

The trick is to insert a 'clear:both' on the first  of each row.

```
 <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="student in students" style="{{$index % 3 == 0 && 'clear:both'}}">
```

This normally will tie the code to the number of rows, but then again so does `<div class="col-md-4"` ,so you might be ok when doing so.

Comment: Thanks but, I want the rest of the elements to align in the left out space not to shift them down.